# Read a specific section of a file

Tags: python

I have a text file which has plenty of text and a block like this:

```
text text text text text text text text text
TMP   [%]        [KT]      [PR]      [SF]   
1    0.10020    -0.0000      -60.0     0.0000
2   14.12826     0.0000        0.0     0.0000
3    4.00802  -120.3636       -6.0   191.5646
4    4.80962     0.0000        0.0     0.0000
text text text text text text text text text
```

I would like to read the rows from 1-4 and dump those values to some array (column wise/row wise) so that I can use them later.

```
tr=4  #number of rows after row starting with "TMP"
f =open("test.txt", "r")
fr = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i in len(tr):
    for line in fr:
      if line.startswith('  TMP'):# neglect other text and start with line containing TMP
        line=line+1
        print line
```

Somehow this does not seem to work. What I have done is detected a line that has "TMP" and move ahead to read the next 4 lines. How can I read 4 lines like mentioned above?

Comment: "_Somehow this does not seem to work_". How so? Does it crash? If so, what is the error message? Does it run, but produce the wrong output? If so, what is the wrong output, and what output do you expect?

Comment: line=line+1
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Comment: `len(tr)` should have been either `len(fr)` or `tr` - but the implementation of the cycle is a bit twisted - what is the purpose of the outer `for` loop plz?

Comment: @deathApril: No, not at all. Do you want to read the file as many times at the number of lines it contains?

Comment: I want to read the 4 lines after the line that starts with "TMP". The file is read only once.

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message produced by this code? Because I would expect `for i in len(tr):` to give you a TypeError (both because you can't `len` an integer, and even if you could, you couldn't iterate over the return value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
data=[]

for index,line in enumerate(fr):
    if line.startswith('TMP'):# neglect other text and start with line containing TMP
      for i in range(4): 
        data.append(fr[index+i+1])
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: that will store the line containing tmp also

Comment: No it won't because range(4) will go from 0 to 3 I've added a 1 to the index :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that what you want to achieve is to start reading the lines if line starts with `'TMP'` or `'  TMP'` and continue reading only the `tr` number of lines, i.e.:

```
interesting_text = false
for line in fr:
  if line.startswith('  TMP'): # neglect other text and start with line containing TMP
    interesting_text = true
  elif interesting_text and tr > 0:
    print line
    tr -= 1
  elif tr == 0:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be nesting those loops in the first place, and you need `xrange()` not `len()`. Also, you don't need to increase the line counter manually (which is what I suspect you intended by `line = line + 1` - which wouldn't work anyway because `line` is a string).

Furthermore, there's no point in reading the entire file into an array. The following is much simpler:

```
tr = 4
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for i in xrange(tr): next(f)  # skip four lines
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('  TMP'): # only print lines containing TMP
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
n = 4  # number of rows
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.xreadlines()
    line = next(lines)
    while 'TMP' not in line:
        line = next(lines)
    line = next(lines)  # skip the TMP line
    for _ in xrange(n):
        print line
        line = next(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not pretty but it will work:

```
    with open('test.txt') as f:
        start = 0
        useful = []
        for ln in f:
            if ln.strip().startswith('TMP'):
                start = 1
            elif start and start < 5:
                useful.append(ln)
                start += 1
            elif start > 4:
                break
```